# Receiving FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, ubuntu, path

For more clarifying information, I am using a Ubuntu 20.04. I am receiving the following error when trying to read a text file from a different directory: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Say that the python code "code.py" that I am trying to run resides in Folder1. The text file "test.txt" that I am trying to read off of is in Folder2, where the relative pathing from "code.py" is "../Folder2/test.txt". However, when I am using: `from pathlib import Path` and
`PATH = Path("..\Folder2\test.txt")`, I receive the error. Is there a better way to go about this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try ```os.path.join('Folder2', 'test.txt')```.

Comment: Thank you so much, this does work for me! However, this now results in another error for me. When I am trying to read a csv file (with pandas) using this method to generate the PATH, it results in the same error. What can I do to alleviate this?

Comment: I should also clarify that this code has to operate for both Linux & Windows users.

Comment: I tried to load a csv file and it works without any errors, check the file name and location.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `os.path.join()`, as it was built to work cross-platform(Linux/Mac/Windows).